# Windows failed to boot after Ubuntu installation

Tags: windows, boot, bootrepair

Recently I installed Ubuntu on my Windows machine, thereafter I am unable to windows fails to start. None of the options given in startup-repair of Windows doesn't help.

Moreover, I am not seeing the Windows partition files through Ubuntu, here I am attaching the GParted disk list.

I wonder, whether Windows is there or deleted? Looks like it is deleted?

Could you please guide me here, so that I can boot in Windows.

Here is a [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/LYGCRwDe) of the boot-repair log.

[image]

Comment: Is that the only disk in your machine?  If so, it's not looking good for your Windows installation...

Comment: Yes, it is only disk

Comment: If that is the complete list of partitions on your drive (which it does look like based on size totals compared to the total capacity) then it does indeed look like you overwrote your main Windows partition and Windows is, unfortunately, gone.  Neither the remaining NTFS partition nor the fat32 partition are your Windows installation.

Comment: Indeed, as @squillman just commented, Windows was overwritten. **How that happened was due to user error.** Provided users follow the correct instructions to prepare it - use Windows tools to shrink Windows partitions in order to make room for the second OS - then using the automated installation procedure of "install alongside..." NEVER does this. When you do the partitioning manually - you certainly can - then you must know what you're doing.

Comment: is there any way to recover it ?

Comment: Only from backup.  Likely not even a data recovery service will be able to get it back fully since the physical space on the disk was overwritten with the ext4 partitions.  If you don't have a good backup, then unfortunately you will not be able to recover your Windows installation.

Comment: Dual boot is (frankly) the dumbest thing in the world. Few people truly need it. Learn a lesson here and use a tool like VirtualBox in the future to use Ubuntu. It works just as fine and is far less risky.

Comment: VM's are certainly safer and, generally, a much better way to use multiple operating systems.  Dual boot absolutely has its place, though.  It is not unusual that an application requires direct hardware access, or the video drivers inside a VM are not sufficient.  But if you are not doing any heavy lifting it is most definitely much better to install one OS and run the other inside a VM.

Comment: Looks like you nuked the Windows installation with Ubuntu. The data on the Windows partition was overwritten with your Ubuntu installation. Only reason Windows is even attempting to boot is because of the EFI entry.

Answer (score 2):

While your question lacks certain helpful info such as the specific steps you performed installing Ubuntu, the picture, and your statement there is only one drive in your computer indicates you overwrote your entire drive during the Ubuntu installation process.

As commentors have noted, the specific things that have happened to your drive mean there is only the smallest chance your data can be recovered at this point. Having a good backup is your best chance, and really, it's what you should have already before doing this sort of thing.

Going forward: use a virtual machine to run your secondary OSes. It's far safer, and also more convenient and easy. Backup your data regularly, especially before any sort of system changes, do a lot more research before doing things like this. Dual booting is very possible, but it has some caveats, and you need to know what you're doing before you start.